# Fitting a quadratic polynomial to two points such that it is always concave downward

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Given two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, I'd like to construct a quadratic polynomial of the form $y = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ such that it intersects both points and is [concave downward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) (i.e., has a global maximum but no minimum). The maximum does not have to occur between the two points.

Since two points are not sufficient to fully determine a quadratic system, I'm currently setting $a_0 = 0$ and computing $a_2$ and $a_1$ as follows:

$$a_2 = \frac{x_2y_1 - x_1y_2}{x_1^2x_2 - x_1x_2^2}$$

(The $a_2$ formula is derived by solving $y_1 = a_2x_1^2 + \frac{x_1}{x_2}(y_2 - a_2x_2^2)$ for $a_2$.)

$$a_1 = \frac{y_1 - a_2x_1^2}{x_1}$$

This produces a quadratic polynomial that passes through both points, but does nothing to ensure that it is always concave downward.

This problem is similar to the one answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31573/finding-a-third-degree-equation-that-fits-two-points-with-given-slopes), except that the slopes at the two points are unspecified, although the following situations are possible:

- Both slopes are positive
- Both slopes are negative
- The slope at point 1 is positive and the slope at point 2 is negative.

However, I'm unsure of how to apply these constraints; I don't know how inequalities - as opposed to equalities, as in the aforementioned question - involving the derivative could be applied in this case.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using $-x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$ instead.

Comment: Good suggestion, @Antonio; it worked. If you'd like to propose this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

$$
p(x) = -x^2 + a_1 x + a_0.
$$

Taking the first coefficient to be $-1$ (or any other negative number) ensures that the parabola is concave down.  Then one just needs to solve the equations

$$
p(x_1) = y_1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad p(x_2) = y_2
$$

for $a_1$ and $a_0$, yielding

$$
a_0 = \frac{x_1 x_2^2 - x_1^2 x_2 + x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1}{x_1 - x_2},
$$

$$
a_1 = \frac{x_1^2 - x_2^2 + y_1 - y_2}{x_1-x_2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $y_2>y_1$ and $x_1\neq x_2$.  Note that this is not too burdensome; if $x_1=x_2$ there is no solution; if $y_2<y_1$ you reverse the two points; if $y_2=y_1$ it's not too hard to solve.  Then consider

$$y=-a(x-x_2)^2+b$$

You now choose $a,b$ to pass through the two points you want.  To pass through $(x_2,y_2)$ you need $b=y_2$.  To pass through $(x_1,y_1)$ you need $y_1=-a(x_1-x_2)^2+y_2$, which rearranges to $$a=-\frac{y_1-y_2}{(x_1-x_2)^2}$$

Since $y_2>y_1$, we must have $a>0$ so it is indeed a parabola, and points downward.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, vadim123. However, I prefer the approach Antonio Vargas proposed as it doesn't require the points to be switched if $y_2 < y_1$ (thus avoiding the need for this to be checked).